# Is there a way to set the scrollbar skin globally in a Flex Spark application?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I have a custom skin class that I want to apply to all scrollbars. Is there a way to set this globally in a Flex Spark application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
s|Scroller
{
 skinClass: com.x.y;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys I got it working :)

I place this code in the Application style tag (a style sheet would work as well),

```
<fx:Style>
    @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
    @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";
    @namespace skins "skins.*";

    s|HScrollBar
    {
        skinClass: ClassReference("skins.HScrollBarSkin");
    }

    s|VScrollBar
    {
        skinClass: ClassReference("skins.VScrollBarSkin");
    }
</fx:Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Best answer is that you apply that style to the parentApplication that means in the first page you just give that style and then it will apply to all the sub page. such like that

```
<mx:Style source="Style/Style.css" />
```

give that to all the parent page in your application.

Have a nice day.

Style.css

```
Application 
{
    backgroundColor: #FFFFFF;
    themeColor: #6C76D3;
    color: #333333;
}

.NumButton 
{
    color: #000000;
    width: 35;
    font-weight:bold;
}

Accordion 
{
    borderStyle: solid;
    headerHeight: 32;
    textIndent: 0;
    openDuration: 219;
    fillAlphas: 1, 1, 0.7, 0.7;
    fillColors: #EBF0F3, #8E8FCC, #6273C9, #263692;
    selectedFillColors: #D5DBE3, #8E8FCC;
    headerStyleName: "myaccordionHeader";   
}

AccordionHeader 
{
    borderStyle: solid;
    headerHeight: 36;
    textIndent: 0;
    openDuration: 219;
    fillAlphas: 0.4, 0.5, 0.7, 0.7;
    fillColors: #DEE1FF, #AEBEFF, #8C86FF, #5646D3;
    selectedFillColors: #AEBEFF, #8C86FF;
    headerStyleName: "myaccordionHeader";
}
.myaccordionHeader 
{
    color: #1F213C;
    fontFamily: Tahoma;
    fontSize: 12;
}
```

Comment: That is helpful but only part of the answer. What does the code for that style look like (what is in the Style.css)?

Comment: Style.css is the StyleSheet name. and you can give that in all your parentApplication. its a lengthy code that's why i can't give you.. Sorry for that...

Comment: I fail to see how this answers the question. Unlike user293531's (god that was hard to write) concise and to the point response.

Comment: hey bug-a-lot,

I have given the answer first and then 1.21 gigawatts want to know what's there in the css file. and then i have edited the answer and add css file into it.. If you have any other suggestion pls give .

Comment: Sagar - the question requires the answer user293531 provided for it to be complete. i've chosen yours for the answer because it's the first part in what i have to do, the second being the CSS code for the s|Scroller component. but users answer is incomplete without yours. anyway, thanks the important thing is its working :)